# How to use scope in include option when creating a record with sequelize

Tags: sequelize.js

We're trying to create a record in our Postgresql database from sequelize utilizing the include options. However, one of the associations (comment) has a scope, and the parent (post) has the association to the child (comment) with the scope. It appears that sequelize should be adding a value to a certain field based on the scope that is provided however, it is not doing so and instead the field remains blank.

We're using sequelize, postgres, javascript, express router.

We've tried adding an association to comment (naming it with the "as" property), but that just throws the error "address is associated to civilian using an alias. You must use the 'as' keyword to specify the alias within your include statement."

We've modified the data before it gets sent to the sequelize model, and that seems to work but seems hacky and we'd prefer that this be done by sequelize since it seems like this is some functionality of it.

We can also just add the row of data to the other table manually, side-stepping sequelize, but run into the same issue of it being hacky.

createPage file - include options for create Page

```js
const includeOptions = [{
  model: models.post,
  as: "specialPosts",
  auditUser: request.nickname,
  include: [{
    model: models.comment,
    // as: "postComments",
    auditUser: request.nickname
  }]
}];

/***** Modification of Data Mentioned Before Sending to Sequelize *****/
pageAttributes.posts[0].comment.commentableType = 'post';

/***** Create Page *****/
const createdPage = await models.pages.create(pageAttributes, queryOptions);
```

comment model - commentableType field

```js
commentableType: {
  type: DataTypes.ENUM([
    COMMENTABLE_TYPE.POST,
    COMMENTABLE_TYPE.IMAGE
  ]),
  field: "commentable_type"
}
```

post model - comment association

```js
Post.hasOne(models.comments, {
  // as: "postComments",
  foreignKey: {
    name: "commentableId",
    field: "commentable_id"
  },
  scope: {
    commentable_type: COMMENTABLE_TYPE.POST
  }
});
```

We expect that by adding the nested comment include in the main post include that sequelize will know to fill in the commentable_type field with the correct enum.